# Rails embed image in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I'm trying to embed (inline) an image (logo) into an email.

This is the invoice.mailer.rb:

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invoice_email(invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    @recipients = @invoice.workorder.client.contacts.where(:receiveinvoices => true)
    tomail = @recipients.collect(&:email).join(",")
    frommail = @invoice.tenant.from_email
    copymail = @invoice.tenant.copy_email
    attachments.inline['AME_Logo.gif'] = File.read( Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/AME_Logo.gif') )

    mail(
        :to => tomail,
        :bcc => copymail,
        :from => frommail,
        :subject => "New Invoice from " + @invoice.tenant.name

    )
  end
end
```

This is the _invoice_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 700px">
<div class="invoice">
<div class="inv_header" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right: auto; width: 650px">
  <h4>Invoice</h4>
  <%= image_tag attachments['AME_Logo.gif'].url -%>
</div>
```

I'm getting this error from the image_tag code line:

```
undefined local variable or method `attachments' for #<#<Class:0x007f8a49ce7b08>:0x007f8a4e352110>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just hard-code the path in your image_tag helper?

```
<%= image_tag('http://path-to-your-site/assets/AME_Logo.gif') %>
```

If it must be an attachment, you have to make it an instance variable:

```
@attachments.inline['AME_Logo.gif'] = File.read( Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/AME_Logo.gif') )
```

and in your mailer:

```
<%= image_tag @attachments['AME_Logo.gif'].url -%>
```

Comment: I have tried `<%= image_tag("/images/AME_Logo.gif", :class => 'pull-right padding-right') %>` - The image is an attachment, but not inline.